# Chrome packaged apps: Permission for getUserMedia() audio input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, web-audio-api, google-chrome-app

I'm porting my web app over to a Chrome packaged app and I heavily use the Web Audio API (which works great), but I use getUserMedia() to get line in audio.  Normally a status bar comes down asking for permission from the user.  In a packaged app this does not happen and error 1 (permission denied) is thrown.  Has anyone had any experience with this in a packaged app setting or know if there is a certain permission I need to add?

Oh, I also did some research and found some bugs filed with chrome on it but I don't know if any of them have been implemented yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the proper permissions in your manifest.json. Then it should inform the user when they install your app.

```
  "permissions": [
    "audioCapture", 
    "videoCapture"
  ]
```

You can use one or the other depending on what type of request you're passing as a parameter to getUserMedia(), that is {audio:true} or {video:true}, respectively.

Comment: Awesome.  That worked perfectly.  I couldn't find it in Chromes documentation.  Thanks alot!

Comment: The docs are little confusing in that they say these aren't possible. A little poking around and some testing proved that to be not true. Cheers.